Find the $L_2$ projection on the set $S$
Let $f\in L_2[0,1]$ and $S = \{h\in L_2[0,1]:\; \int h = 1,h\geq 0\}$. What is the $L_2$ projection of $f$ on $S$? I guess that it is not available in closed-form?
I would guess that the projection is $(f-\lambda)_+$, where $\lambda$ solves $\int (f-\lambda)_+ = 1$. Is this correct?

Do you mean the closest point? $S$ is not a subspace. The finite dimensional equivalent does not have a closed form, so it seems unlikely that the $L^2$ version would have.

$S$ is indeed not a subspace but it is closed an convex I guess? So the projection still makes sense

Let $\lambda=\int_0^1f(x) dx-1$. If $h(x)=f(x)-\lambda$ satisfies $h(x)\geq0$ then this is the projection. To see why, note that the projection $\tilde h\in S$ satisfies $\int_0^1 f(x)-\tilde h(x) dx=\lambda$ and among all functions with a given integral, the constant function has the least $L^2$ norm; this can be proved using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
